npm package to find the total no of slides present in the uploaded pptx file using nodejs
In the Node.js project, I need an npm package that can determine the number of slides present in a .pptx file. I tried using the node-pptx package, but it doesn't seem to provide a method for retrieving the total slide count for a .pptx file. Is there a way to find the total number of slides present in the .pptx file?
